# Cutting a Circle chunk out of a Cube

Tags: subdivision-surface

Hello I've been having an issue creating what would resemble a turn in a skate park on blender.

Essentially what i want is a cube with the quadrant of a sphere centered at one of the cubes top corners to be cut away from square and replaced with a surface like the spheres.

Heres an ide of what each side would look like

[image]

And hers what it looks like isometrically:

[image]

I've tried putting a sphere there and then cutting away the uneeded parts but then the inside surface of the sphere on the cube isnt rendered. Can anyone help me understand how best to make this kind of cut?

cube = scale 3

sphere = radius 5, rings and columns ~500 (just becasue that is what the other pieces ring the circles for)

Comment: your question isn't about subdivision surface but about boolean

Comment: Don't use Booleans, it will only lead to issues. Manually model it from a sphere section, it will yield much better results

Comment: **1.** Enable the Extra Objects add-on. **2.** Add Mesh > Round Cube. **3.** Delete all but one corner of the round cube. **4.** Select the non-manifold edges of the round cube and extrude them into a cube shape to make the angular sides of the object. **5.** Fill any faces that need filling. **6.** Recalculate Normals. Done!